How to connect to Redis Instance with Encryption in ECS
we currently have a aws serverless redis instance with encryption in transit enabled. So our conneciton string looks something like this elasticredis.xxx.com:6379,ssl=True,sslProtocols=Tls12|Tls13. When I deploy to my ec2 instance, my .net api works fine. But the moment I deploy to a aws ecs container, it fails.
It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). Error connecting right now. To allow this multiplexer to continue retrying until it's able to connect, use abortConnect=false in your connection string or AbortOnConnectFail=false; in your code
Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

There is literally no difference in the settings or code to connect to Redis when running on EC2 versus ECS. I would check that the Redis security group allows your ECS tasks/services to connect like it allows your EC2 instance to connect.
